How to fix an error "SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction"?
I have an issue that periodically appears due to the launch of the job class in the command on the Laravel Framework 10.48.10 project.
Exception text:
"SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (Connection: mysql, SQL: delete from jobs where id = 10164)"
"Exception
{
    "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
    "message": "SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (Connection: mysql, SQL: delete from `jobs` where `id` = 10164)",
    "code": 40001,
    "file": "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:829",
    "trace": [
        "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:783",
        "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:619",
        "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:564",
        "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:3756",
        "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php:357",
        "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php:30",
        "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php:359",
        "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/DatabaseJob.php:66",
        "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php:82",
        "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php:102",
        "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:439",
        "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:389",
        "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:176",
        "

I also have a slightly different error text, but it is also error 1213 Deadlock:
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from jobs where queue = default and ((reserved_at is null and available_at <= 1722524426) or (reserved_at <= 1722524336)) order by id asc limit 1 for update)
Exception
```{
   "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
   "message": "SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from jobs where queue = default and ((reserved_at is null and available_at <= 1722524426) or (reserved_at <= 1722524336)) order by id asc limit 1 for update)",
   "code": 40001,
   "file": "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:829",
   "trace": [
       "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:783",
       "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:431",
       "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2872",
       "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2860",
       "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:3414",
       "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2861",
       "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php:333",
       "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php:246",
       "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php:224",
       "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php:30",
       "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php:227",
       "/var/www/vhosts/index.parsoft.io/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/`…

I have a first command GoogleIndexSearchedCarsCommand with job.
Launching in the Kernel.php:
$schedule->command('app:google-index-searched-cars-command')->hourly()->between('10:00', '23:59')->withoutOverlapping();

Inside the command GoogleIndexSearchedCarsCommand I have this code where I run the job:
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Jobs\GoogleIndexSearchedCarsJob;
use App\Services\ResourceLibraryHiddenCar\ResourceLibraryHiddenCarService;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class GoogleIndexSearchedCarsCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'app:google-index-searched-cars-command';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * @var ResourceLibraryHiddenCarService
     */
    private ResourceLibraryHiddenCarService $resourceLibraryHiddenCarService;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->resourceLibraryHiddenCarService = app(ResourceLibraryHiddenCarService::class);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        $this->googleIndexSearchedCars();
    }

    private function googleIndexSearchedCars(): void
    {
        $resources = $this->resourceLibraryHiddenCarService->getResourcesForGoogleIndexingCars(typeIndexing: 'searched');
        if ($resources->isNotEmpty()) {
            foreach ($resources as $resource) {
                GoogleIndexSearchedCarsJob::dispatch($resource);
            }
        }
    }
}

I also have a second similar command GoogleIndexHiddenCarsCommand  with job.
Launching in the Kernel.php:
$schedule->command('app:google-index-hidden-cars-command')->hourlyAt(30)->between('10:00', '23:59')->withoutOverlapping();

Inside this command this code:
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Jobs\GoogleIndexHiddenCarsJob;
use App\Services\ResourceLibraryHiddenCar\ResourceLibraryHiddenCarService;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class GoogleIndexHiddenCarsCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'app:google-index-hidden-cars-command';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * @var ResourceLibraryHiddenCarService
     */
    private ResourceLibraryHiddenCarService $resourceLibraryHiddenCarService;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->resourceLibraryHiddenCarService = app(ResourceLibraryHiddenCarService::class);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        $this->googleIndexHiddenCars();
    }

    private function googleIndexHiddenCars(): void
    {
        $resources = $this->resourceLibraryHiddenCarService->getResourcesForGoogleIndexingCars(typeIndexing: 'hidden');
        if ($resources->isNotEmpty()) {
            foreach ($resources as $resource) {
                GoogleIndexHiddenCarsJob::dispatch($resource);
            }
        }
    }

}

What is the reason for the Deadlock error? How to fix it? Please help.

Are you sing MySQL 5.7?

MariaDB 10.5.23 Debian 11

Hmm, I can't say much about MariaDB, but this is a known issue when using Laravel queue with MySQL 5.7 and below. The workaround was to upgrade to MySQL 8 or use some other queue driver such as redis, sqs, etc. I don't know if there's a MariaDB version where this error no longer exists, so you will have to check it out
